# Invalid ELF header xgboost (using a pkl in a Docker container)

Tags: python, docker, xgboost

I have a pkl file which uses the library xgboost.
In my code I just import this pkl and load it:

```
def _init_model(self):
    self.model = joblib.load(QueryClassifier.MODEL_FILE)
```

Also I am running my code inside a Docker container.
I have a requirements file like this one:

```
scipy
sklearn
numpy
xgboost
pandas
flask
```

I have this error when I try to run the Docker Container:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 12, in <module>
    c = classifier.QueryClassifier()
  File "/app/classifier_controller/classifier.py", line 43, in __init__
    self._init_model()
  File "/app/classifier_controller/classifier.py", line 62, in _init_model
    self.model = joblib.load(QueryClassifier.MODEL_FILE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 575, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 507, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1039, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1334, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1384, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .core import DMatrix, Booster
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 112, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 106, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so: invalid ELF header
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build xhboost .

See https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/463